# 000webhosting appending script

Tags: php

I'm tearing my hair out with these guys. I'm trying to work on my ajax, and they're making it extremely difficult. If I make an ajax request or try to use a page as a javascript tag's source, they automatically append:

```
<!-- www.000webhost.com Analytics Code -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>

<noscript><a href="http://www.hosting24.com/"><img src="http://analytics.hosting24.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript>

<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Can I do anything about this?

Comment: Use a decent host.

Comment: That is probably a HTTPD module that appends the text on the fly so in short I dont think you have many options you would have to do something clientside, with javascript or anything else. So you should just do what Slaks said above :)

Comment: I don't have money to afford a decent host. Are there any good free ones?

Comment: @Walkerneo x10hosting is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the beginning of an HTML comment at the end of every page:

```
<!--
```

In the case of an AJAX response try ending with a JS Multiline Comment:

```
/*
```

So if you're using PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array('take that' => 'cheap hosting'));
echo '/*';
```

When you `eval()` the JSON response in Javascript you may need to append a closing comment tag:

```
eval(response.text+'*/');
```

With any luck, the user's browser's HTML parsers will complete the comment (and hide the code your host inserts). I'm fairly certain that an eval within javascript will ignore comments so my second solution should work too. I'm not 100% sure though because I don't have a cheap host to test this on! Let me know if it actually works.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable that by going to:
http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php

No need for workarounds or hacks.

Comment: +1 I use 000webhost sometimes too. It's cool (for a free host) that they let you disable analytics, but they don't exactly make this option easy to find.

Comment: That's true, I found out because I asked in the forum as soon as I realized it was loading something I didn't asked for.